# .NET Missing member when deserialize

Tags: c#, json

I'm using a library that I got an issue. It has a custom exception:

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public CustomException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }

}
```

and a logger serializes it and store it to a database. But when I got it back from a JSON string and deserialize it to Exception by:

```
Exception ex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Exception>(json, settings);
```

It threw an Exception with a message:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Member 'HelpURL' was not found.'
```

Is there a way to help me fix it. Remember that it is a library so I could not do anything in its code.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET 4 or ASP.NET Core? How are you passing the exception? Probably I would return a simpler value (error message), an anonymous type, or a JSON string, rather than trying to rely on .NET to serialize more complex objects or object graphs.

Comment: Create a plain DTO for this. Using something that inherits from Exception in this context, is asking for trouble.

Comment: So can you post the actual JSON and an actual class of this or the library name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialization Error of Member 'HelpURL' was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70984594/deserialization-error-of-member-helpurl-was-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case, I solved the problem by adding the [Serializable] class attribute to the CustomException class.