# Deserialization Error of Member 'HelpURL' was not found

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Getting the exception

> Member 'HelpUrl' was not found

while trying to Deserialize object.
Below is the code i am trying to execute.

```
Log objectLog  = (Log) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
                       JObject.Parse(msg.Body)["Message"].ToString());
```

I have tried
annotating the Log class as `[Serializable]`,
creating constructor for Log class with SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context

Why is it failing?

Comment: Please show us your `JSON` string that you are trying to deserialize and also show us some extracts of your attempt.

Comment: What does the `Log` class look like, and what does the content of `msg.Body` look like?

Comment: Case matters. Is it `HelpUrl` or `HelpURL`? Have you done any research into the error message? For instance, a quick search on the error message found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63444576/215552), which unfortunately never got updated with the JSON and therefore was never answered...

Comment: @RahulSharma, below is the JSON i am trying to deserialize  {
  "Hostname": "MoveNext",
  "Logtime": "2022-02-07T09:41:02.5831679+05:30",
  "LogMessage": "Returned response as Unauthorized Access",
  "Exception": { Entire Exception Object }
}

Comment: @MikeHofer, the Log class and msg.Body has the same set of properties. FYI, I am able to deserialize the string when there no exception object in it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, yes i did some analysis and same issue have found and reported multiple times <br/>[link]https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2209 <br/>[link]https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31346<br/>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63444576/net-missing-member-when-deserialize

Comment: Just [edit] your question with your responses. Later readers should not need to dig through comments to understand the question.

Comment: Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51825756/json-exception-deserializing-into-the-proper-type describes how to handle not-serializable exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the object being serialized had a `CustomException` class derived from `System.Exception`. I imagine you can have a similar situation.

As I detailed in [.NET Missing member when deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63444576/net-missing-member-when-deserialize/72924771#72924771). (thanks Heretic for linking us to this related post), I could solved the problem by adding the `[Serializable]` attribute to the `CustomException` class.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was where the serializing was in a project using `System.Text.Json`. After using `Mvc.NewtonSoftJson` both for serializing and deserializing went ok.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting exception from json string and it can be not serializable.
So I have to handle and log the error.

```
 Exception SafeDeserializeException(string maskedExceptionString)
 {
        try
        {
            ret = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Exception>(maskedExceptionString);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            ret=return new Exception($"{deserializationException.Message} Data: {maskedExceptionString}"
                , exc); 
        } 
        return ret;
 }
```